# jquery mobile popup disappers on ipad when keyboard visible

Tags: jquery, mobile, popup

I have popup working. When use IPAD and click on input field, keyboard shows and popup disappears when text input field got focus. Here popup panel code. Please help.

```
<div data-role="panel" data-id="popover1" data-panel="popover" class="ui-element-fixed-top  ui-triangle-top 
     ui-mobile-viewport ui-panel ui-popover ui-panel-active ui-fixed-overlay" 
    status="hidden" style="top: 0px; display: none; width: 500px; height: 445px; right: 100px; margin-top: 45px;">
      <div class="popover_triangle"></div>

    <div data-role="page" data-show="first" id="popover1-1" data-url="popover1-1" tabindex="0" data-internal-page="true" >
        <div  class="ui-content" role="main" style="font-family: Georgia; font-weight:bold; ">              
            <div  class="ui-field-contain ui-body ui-br" style="height:50px" >
                <label for="email" class="ui-input-text" style="text-align: right">Email:</label>
                <input type="email" name="email" id="email" value="" 
                 class="ui-body-c ui-corner-all ui-shadow-inset" style="width: 340px">
              </div>
                    <div data-role="fieldcontain" class="ui-field-contain ui-body ui-br" style="height:50px">
            <label for="author" class="ui-input-text" style="text-align: right">Book author:</label>
            <input type="text" name="author" id="author" value="" 
            class="ui-input-text ui-body-c ui-corner-all ui-shadow-inset" style="width: 340px">
        </div>
        <div data-role="fieldcontain" class="ui-field-contain ui-body ui-br" style="height:70px">
            <label for="title" class="ui-input-text" style="text-align: right">Book title:</label>
            <input type="text" name="title" id="title" value="" 
            class="ui-input-text ui-body-c ui-corner-all ui-shadow-inset" style="width: 340px">
        </div>

             <a href="docs-dialogs.html"  data-rel="back"  data-corners="true" data-shadow="true" data-iconshadow="true" data-wrapperels="span" 
                    class="closePanel ui-btn ui-btn-up-a ui-shadow ui-btn-corner-all" id="btnSend" onclick="send();">
                    <span class="ui-btn-inner ui-btn-corner-all">
                    <span class="ui-btn-text">Send</span></span></a>       


                    <a href="docs-dialogs.html" data-role="button" data-rel="back"  data-corners="true" data-shadow="true" 
                    data-iconshadow="true" data-wrapperels="span" 
                    class="closePanel ui-btn ui-btn-up-c ui-shadow ui-btn-corner-all"><span class="ui-btn-inner ui-btn-corner-all">
                    <span class="ui-btn-text">Cancel</span></span></a>    
    </div>
</div><!-- end page-->
```

Comment: Could you please provide some code of what you've tried?

Comment: here how i call popup <a href="#" data-transition="pop" data-theme="a" 
                        data-role="button" data-panel="popover1"  data-inline="true"  class="toggle_popover ui-btn ui-btn-inline  ui-corner-left ui-btn-up-a">
                        <span class="ui-btn-inner ui-corner-left" aria-hidden="true">
                        <span class="ui-btn-text">request book</span><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-lang ui-icon-shadow"></span></span></a>

Comment: Check my answer for a possible work around. This bug came just in with iOS 7.

Answer (score 1):

I am facing the same situation here:

We have an iPad application that uses the iOS API browser component (UIWebView) to display a html page holding a set of tools based on Jquery, Jquerymobile and KineticJS.
We use many of the jquery widgets, mostly popups.

There is a specific situation when opening a specific popup that includes a text input.
The popup appears as expected when invoked - however, just when the User touches the input text and the iPad's virtual keyboard is revealed, the popup disappears.
It might also be that it does not disappear at all but rather gets "moved" in a way that it can no longer be seen.

This does not happen when we test the page through the iPad built-in Safari browser. In this case, the popup behaves correctly and gets pushed a little bit by the virtual keyboard, but as soon as the keyboard disappears the popup returns to its initial position.

I believe this started on iOS 7 and above - I recall using this in previous iOS versions without any problem.

I tested with JQM 1.3.2 and 1.4.0.

The JQM team is working on the issue:

https://github.com/jquery/jquery-mobile/issues/6961

---

WORKAROUND UPDATE:

Setting the focus() on the input text in the popup, just in the "afteropen" event for the popup seems to work-around the situation for at least making it viable to accept User input: both popup and keyboard are displayed correctly and user can input...